# Evitar valores duplicados C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Buenas me gustaria hacerles una pregunta, como puedo hacer para verificar que el valor escrito en un textbox no este repetido en la tabla de la base de datos esta seria una porcion del codigo que se encuentra en la capa de presentacion antes de ser mandado al metodo insertar en la logica de negocios.

```
public override bool EjecutarComandoNuevo()
    {
        if (!VerificarDatosObligatorios())
        {
            MessageBox.Show(@"Por favor ingrese los campos Obligatorios.", @"Atención", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return false;
        }

        var nuevaProvincia = new ProvinciaDto
        {
            Descripcion = txtDescripcion.Text,
        };

        _provinciaServicio.Insertar(nuevaProvincia);

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrias usa algo como esto

```
public bool Existe(string parametro)  
{  
    string sql = @"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <Tabla> WHERE campo = @param";   
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connection string"))   
    {   
        conn.Open();  

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);   
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", parametro);   

        int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());   

        return count == 0;   
    }   
}
```

la idea es que pases el valor que identifica a la entidad y la uses en el `where` del sql, pudiendo ver la cantidad de registros que existen, sino hay ninguno entonces es que no esta duplicado